# Build nsis: Error initalizing CEXEBuild: error setting default stub

Tags: installation, nsis, scons

I want to build the latest version of `nsis` on linux. At the beginning I installed the packages `python3 scons zlib1g-dev libcppunit-dev gcc-mingw-w64`.

I downloaded `nsis-3.04-src` and run `scons SKIPUTILS=all SKIPMISC=all NSIS_CONFIG_CONST_DATA_PATH=no PREFIX=/usr/bin/ install-compiler install-subs` like at the [documentation for posix](https://nsis.sourceforge.io/Docs/AppendixG.html).

But I get this error message:

```
Error: reading stub "/usr/Stubs/zlib-x86-ansi"
Error initalizing CEXEBuild: error setting default stub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must download the [zip file](https://sourceforge.net/projects/nsis/files/NSIS%203/3.04/) with the stubs and place them in `/usr/Stubs`. Or you can build them yourself with the mingw cross-compiler. The same applies to the plug-ins...

Comment: Where should I copy the plug-ins? To ``/usr/Plugins``? And how could I build them too?

Comment: I think the compiler will list the plug-in directories if you run it with the verbose option. Remove the SKIP SCons commands to cross-compile more things. MinGW will produce larger files if that matters.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand exactly where I should copy the Plugins? Because I get now error messages like ``Plugin not found, cannot call nsExec::Exec``.

Comment: Add `!verbose 4` before the plug-in call. With the latest NSIS version it should print the plug-in directory list. You can also use `!addplugindir` to add custom directories if you want to keep them somewhere else (You can use a configure .nsh file in your home directory to do this).

Answer (score 0):

```
git clone https://github.com/kichik/nsis.git 
wget https://jaist.dl.sourceforge.net/project/nsis/NSIS%203/3.05/nsis-3.05.zip
```

1. unzip

```
# unzip nsis-3.05.zip -d /usr/local
```

2. compiler and install

```
# cd nsis
# scons-3 SKIPSTUBS=all SKIPPLUGINS=all SKIPUTILS=all SKIPMISC=all \
      NSIS_CONFIG_CONST_DATA_PATH=no PREFIX=/usr/local/nsis-3.05/Bin \
      install-compiler
```

3. create link

```
# ln -s /usr/local/nsis-3.05/Bin/makensis /usr/local/bin/makensis
```